# https "bindings" in Linux with XSP4 server

Tags: asp.net, linux, mono, xsp4

I'm sitting with a bit of a interesting situation. I have a customer that want to try and host their ASP.NET WebAPI from a Linux server. Obviously setting this up on Windows is reasonably straight forward, but I've gotten stuck at the point where one needs set up the "bindings" for the application.

Simply running `xsp4 --https --p12file=cert.pfx --pkpwd=lolno` results in the server being active, but any request returns a "SSL_HELLO_MALFORMED" issue.

I got a similar issue on Windows 10 with IIS when I forgot to do the bindings in the IIS control panel. IS there a similar process for XSP4 on Linux whereby you bind the site to the https protocol with a specific certificate in order to fix this problem and get things to run?

From what I can tell the application isn't too complicated so it shouldn't have any compatibility issues with Mono.

Comment: Migrate to .NET Core and that’s the only feasible approach today and in the future.

Comment: @LexLi I would gladly if the application was mine, it's sadly a packaged API application from a third-party that I've been tasked to deploy. I do not have the source code on hand to port it and the company that made it seems to have no plans of porting it to .NET Core in the foreseeable future. I asked.

Comment: If it comes from a third party, then using it on Mono can simply kill your time further. Rarely such products were designed and tested with Mono/Linux in mind and tons of compatibility issues are there (performance, file system for instance) even for the simplest scenarios. Stick to Windows and .NET Framework if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end there was nothing that could be done to make it run on Linux. Sadly the Mono framework is just too different to .NET and we were forced to set up a Windows Server to address the issues.